# Partition function of a double-stranded dna molecule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I have a doubled-stranded dna molecule. The molecule has N links, each of which can be one of two states: a closed state and an open state with energy $\epsilon$. A link can be open only if the link on his left is already open or on his right for the second case.

I have to find the partition function in 2 different cases. When the molecule "unzip" only at one end and if both end can "unzip".

I can write the partition function (Z) = $\sum_i e^{-\beta E_i}$ , where $\beta = \frac{1}{kt}$

If I understand correctly, $E_i$ means the energy for that specific state.
Thus, If I want the energy for all states, $Z = \sum_i e^{-\beta (N \epsilon)}$ Where N is the open links.

If I'm correct, I don't see any difference between the 2 cases, unzip one end or both end. This let me think that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework I will not give you the solution but some clues. As you say, the energy of a configuration containing $k$ open links is $k\epsilon$. Note, however, that the number of ways of arranging $k$ open links in the two systems is different.

- In the first case links can be broken only from the left side. Therefore, $k$ open links means that the first $k$ links on the left are all broken: you have a single configuration for each $k$ and your partition function is correct (as long as your sum runs from $0$ to $N$).
- In the second case links can be broken from both sides. As a result, $k$ open links correspond to more than one configuration. You have to take into account this "multiplicity" (or degeneration, if you will) when summing up the contributions to the partition function.

Try to explicitly write down the partition function for small values of $N$ (say 3 or 4) and use those results to guide you in deriving the right expression.